# hamburger menu with following code is not working in jquery. I'm using a variable to check its status

Tags: jquery, hamburger-menu

I'm using the following code to open and close a hamburger menu with jquery. I think I'm messing up with either menustatus variable or if condition.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var menustatus = 0;
if(menustatus==0){
    menustatus=1;
    $(".hamburgerMenuIcon").click(function(){
        $(".menu").css("display", "block");
    });
};
else{
    menustatus=0;
    $(".hamburgerMenuIcon").click(function(){
        $(".menu").css("display", "block");
    });
}
```

});

Comment: do you really need all of this? you could just `slideToggle`

Comment: `$(".hamburgerMenuIcon").click(function(){
        $(".menu").slideToggle();
    });` inside the ready function

Comment: Try removing the semi-colon before the else. It may be that the else is never getting called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better CSS-only solution:

```css
ul.menu {
  display: none;
}

#toggle-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: -10px;
  opacity: 0;
}
  #toggle-menu:checked ~ ul.menu {
    display: block;
  }
  
  #toggle-menu:checked ~ label.burger::after {
    content: ' ×';
  }

label.burger {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-menu" />
<label class="burger" for="toggle-menu">&#8942; Menu</label>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need anymore than this :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".hamburgerMenuIcon").click(function(){
          jQuery(".menu").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="hamburgerMenuIcon">TOGGLE</button>

<ul class="menu">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if you don't like the slide, you could just `toggle()` instead

Comment: thank you for the response. When I used the 'slideToggle()' function, on click it did open the menu but it also closes the menu the very next moment.